# Call base class constructor without manually supplying arguments

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6

Imagine that we've the following `class`:

```
class A {
       constructor(x, y, z) {
       }
}

class B extends A {
     constructor(x, y, z) {
         super(x, y, z);
     }
}
```

What if we want to call `super(...)` with `arguments` or *rest arguments*:

```
super.apply(this, arguments);
super.apply(this, args);
```

This won't work: **`super.*` is not allowed before `super()`**.

Is there any alternative to avoid manually supplying arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spread notation:

```
super(...args);
```

E.g.:

```
class B extends A {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
}
```

(`super(...arguments)` would also work.)

But it's worth noting that for the `A` and `B` shown, you don't need to provide a constructor for `B` *at all*. The default constructor¹ for a derived class is exactly as shown above, so:

```
class B extends A {
}
```

would do exactly the same thing.

Further examples below.

In a comment, you said there are 10 (!) parameters to the base class and you only need two of them in your subclass, and my impression is you meant the *first* two. If so:

```
class B extends A {
    constructor(first, second, ...rest) {
        super(first, second, ...rest);
        // Use `first` and `second` here...
    }
}
```

If you meant two in the middle, we can do that with destructuring as well:

```
class B extends A {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        let {1: second, 2: third} = args;
        // Use `second` and `third` here...
    }
}
```

More Examples:

```js
class A {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    console.log(`A: ${x}, ${y}, ${z}`);
  }
}

// No constructor defined; gets default
class B1 extends A {}

// Explicit version of the default constructor
class B2 extends A {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}

// Using `arguments` instead:
class B3 extends A {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }
}

// If the subclass accepts different args
class B4 extends A {
  constructor(q, ...rest) {
    super(...rest);
    console.log(`B4: q = ${q}`);
  }
}

class B5 extends A {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    // They don't have to be called `y` and `z`, I'm just being consistent
    let { 1: y, 2: z } = args;
    console.log(`B5: y = ${y}, z = ${z}`);
  }
}

new B1(1, 2, 3);
new B2(4, 5, 6);
new B3(7, 8, 9);
new B4('q', 'x', 'y', 'z');
new B5('first', 'second', 'third');
```

---

¹ *"the default constructor for a subclass is exactly as shown above"* Note how this is different from languages like Java or C#, where the default constructor would accept no args and call `super()`/`base()` with no args.

Comment: `super(...arguments)` I assume?

Comment: @ankr: No, it would be `super(...arguments)` if you wanted to use `arguments`. I'll clarify

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: No, spread notation spreads out the iterable into discrete arguments.

Comment: Oops, I just did a snippet and forgot to include the parts I wanted to say.. :)  Anyway `super(...arguments)` is the way to go.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't know that. It's interesting!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just another related issue. Is it possible to both get all arguments like rest parameters, and also define named parameters? My actual issue is that maybe I need 2 of 10 available parameters in the derived class, and I want to give them all to the super class. AFAIK, I understood it well, if I don't explicitly call `super(...)`, it will pass them all anyway?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: If the named ones you want are at the beginning, it's really easy; in fact I included an example in an edit above just now. If they aren't at the beginning, there are various ways to destructure the arguments, which I can demonstrate if you have a concrete example?

Comment: `My actual issue is that maybe I need 2 of 10 available parameters`, this is one of the reasons I've got into the habit of passing parameters using an object literal instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean that I need two out of 10 parameters and the base class expects the same parameters

Comment: @Keith Yeah, now that you said this, I believe I could solve it using destructuring at constructor level (i.e. `constructor({ whatever = whoKnows })`)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see, since you can use `arguments`, my concern is gone!

Comment: @Keith BTW, as you've answered in your own answer and what @T.J.Crowder answered too, using `arguments` completely solves my issue

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Alternately, say you want only the first two of the arguments: `constructor(a, b, ...rest) { super(a, b, ...rest); /* use a and b */}`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe this is better because it throws away the magic keyword `arguments`, am I right?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I prefer to move away from `arguments` toward more declarative mechanisms, and destructuring gives us just about all the power we need to do so, but any JS programmer should know `arguments` and in strict mode you won't get the performance penalty, so...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I added a couple more examples above. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```js
class A {
       constructor(x, y, z) {
         console.log(x,y,z);
       }
}

class B extends A {
     constructor(x, y, z) {
         super(...arguments);
     }
}

let X = new B(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Ooops, forgot to do the changes.. put the console.logs in and forgot to add the part I wanted.. :)

Comment: Ok ok! Now it makes sense ;P